# Table row was not showing

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am using knockout Js. I want to show the table row with table header when I click another table row in the table. I used this code below. Can anyone help me out?

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.client_details = [{
    name: 'Jack',
    email: 'jack@gmail.io',
    phone: '256987',
    address: 'US',
    dob: '24/01/1975',
    taxid: '125'
  }, {
    name: 'Hari',
    email: 'hari@yahoo.com',
    phone: '247896',
    address: 'chennai',
    dob: '02/01/1975',
    taxid: '255'
  }];

  this.datas = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    phone: '58963287'
  }, {
    name: 'JohnBert',
    email: 'bert@gmail.com',
    phone: '589625887'
  }];
  self.seletedRow = ko.observable();
  self.goToFolder = function(folder) {
    self.seletedRow(folder);
  };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(self.datas));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table width='100%'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width='25%'>Client Name</th>
      <th width='25%'>Email</th>
      <th class='Phone' width='15%'>Phone</th>
      <th class='Address' width='10%'>Address</th>
      <th class='dob' width='15%'>DOB</th>
      <th class='tax' width='15%'>Tax ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: client_details">
    <tr class="table_row">
      <td data-bind="text: name,click: $root.goToFolder"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: dob"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: taxid"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table data-bind="with: seletedRow">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width='25%'>User Name</th>
      <th width='25%'>Email</th>
      <th class='Phone' width='15%'>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: datas">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me to get the table row data using knockout?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far as a [MCVE]?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `with` binding creates a new binding context. Your second `<table>` therefore looks for the `name`, `email` and `phone` properties *inside* the currently selected client.

If you just want to show/hide the second table based on if there's a selection, you can use the `if` binding.

If you want to perform any filters/logic on `data` based on the row that's selected, you can use a `computed`.

Note that I've also moved your `click` binding to the `<tr>`, so you can click anywhere in the row.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.client_details = [{
    name: 'Jack',
    email: 'jack@gmail.io',
    phone: '256987',
    address: 'US',
    dob: '24/01/1975',
    taxid: '125'
  }, {
    name: 'Hari',
    email: 'hari@yahoo.com',
    phone: '247896',
    address: 'chennai',
    dob: '02/01/1975',
    taxid: '255'
  }];

  this.datas = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    phone: '58963287'
  }, {
    name: 'JohnBert',
    email: 'bert@gmail.com',
    phone: '589625887'
  }];
  self.selectedRow = ko.observable();
  self.goToFolder = function(folder) {
    self.selectedRow(folder);
  };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(self.datas));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table width='100%'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width='25%'>Client Name</th>
      <th width='25%'>Email</th>
      <th class='Phone' width='15%'>Phone</th>
      <th class='Address' width='10%'>Address</th>
      <th class='dob' width='15%'>DOB</th>
      <th class='tax' width='15%'>Tax ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: client_details">
    <tr class="table_row" data-bind="click: $root.goToFolder">
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: dob"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: taxid"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table data-bind="if: selectedRow">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width='25%'>User Name</th>
      <th width='25%'>Email</th>
      <th class='Phone' width='15%'>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: datas">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to implement the pagination concept into the above code. Can anyone help me?